# How can I delegate DNS to a separate AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain example.com purchased and owned by one AWS account, and a hosted zone exists in its Route53 service.

I would like to delegate all DNS queries for the apex and any subdomains to a second AWS account, without transferring the domain to the second AWS account.

Is this possible?   If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty common.

In the second account, create a zone for your domain.  That will create two records - NS and SOA.

Go back to the first account, and under Registered Domains select the appropriate domain.  Then edit the Name Server records, pointing to the values in the zone you created in the first step.

Comment: Thanks...it was actually that simple..  Don't know why I had a brain fart.  Deleting the automatically generated hosted zone from the first account helped remove my confusion.  Thanks again!